# This webpage has a redirect loop (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: google-chrome

We have a site that is not working in Google Chrome V44. It works well in IE and Firefox. All of sudden after updating chrome browser to V44, we unable to login to the system and just receiving this problem.
We're trying to figure out as why this is happening. We have 2 instances of our system in our server. Our live site is the one that is not working in Chrome V44 while the other - our demo site is fine. The only difference of the these sites is that our live has SSL. So our first impression is that there's a problem with Chrome V44 with our site with certificate.

I think Chrome can't establish secure connection with the site.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the Network calls in Inspector can you identify what URL is being called repeatedly? Maybe post your live site's URL? There are too many variables here.

Comment: Thanks codehitman. This is the URL. https://tms.exponential-impact.com/

Comment: I'm sorry I'm unable to reproduce the problem, are you behind a local DNS that does redirects? I do however see that `autocomplete.css` file is unreachable.

Comment: It would also help if you share a screenshot of what your Network tab looks like in Chrome's inspector on page load.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a SSL in Chrome V44 where it incorrectly sends a HTTP_HTTPS header to be set, however the HTTPS header is still set correctly. It has been quite widely reported: http://www.zdnet.com/article/brand-new-chrome-44-release-added-a-bug/
https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-44-sending-https-header-by-mistake-breaking-web-applications-everywhere/

In order to stop this, in PHP, I added the following to the very top of my index.php file:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HTTPS'] = 0;
}
?>
```

Ensuring there is no space between the ?> and the next

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had the chrome redirect loop on gmail.

Possibly significantly, I was doing some work involving changing my system time and it hasn't worked since. [This guide](https://techshali.com/fix-webpage-has-redirect-loop-error/) helped to do that.

There is an available work-around, which is to use gmail in incognito mode, which does still work, although requires you to log in each time

Answer (score 0):

In that case I would say this is an internal problem with you organization's setup. I would speak with your SysAdmin or IT staff. But just to be sure, use your phone carrier's internet, or a cafe nearby, basically something off your network to check if you can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with my MVC solution was, i had recently updated complete Nuget packages in my solution. After the update i forgot to update

```
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
```

section with new dll bindings which installed while update. So in my hosting server due to connectionstring issue, i was not overwriting the current .config file. So once i did the update in assemblyBinding section in .config file the issue gone.

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons for the redirect loop. If you are confident your setup is done properly without any errors, then it might be the issue with your browser. You can try the following

1. Deleting cache and cookies
2. Correcting your system time (if it is not set to automatic)
3. Resetting the browser

[Source](https://www.geekdashboard.com/fix-this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this problem, you can try to clear your cookies in your browser

1. Open your Chrome browser.
2. Type "chrome://settings/clearBrowserData" in the address bar and press Enter.
3. Make sure you are clearing items from the Beginning of time. Then select Cookies and other site data. Click the Clear browsing data button.

If find from google search, this tutorial could helps you https://windows10freeapps.com/fix-err_too_many_redirects-error-google-chrome-browser